# How to change the alibaba.com currency converter with the URL (not manually)

Tags: javascript, url, web-scraping, google-sheets, currency

I'm currently "scraping" some alibaba data into google sheets so that I'm always up to date on the latest prices for my raw materials. But I want to be able to pull in the prices in NGN, AKA Nigerian Naira. There's a widget on the alibaba site to change the currency from usd to other currencies including the NGN, but because I'm pulling the data automatically, it's default is USD. Is there an appendage to the URL that will ensure that it pulls prices in NGN? I have light coding experience so I know I might be able to call the currency widget in the URL if I know the names of the right elements and how to submit the form with a command but I've spent days on it and no luck. Anyway, here is a sample URL that directs to the alibaba site with prices in USD:

https://www.alibaba.com/products/dry_Vitamin_A_Palmitate_250_CWD_powder.html?IndexArea=product_en&assessment_company=ASS

Please let me know what I can append on the URL so that it displays prices in NGN. Thanks for your help in this, and in the answers to others questions.

Comment: It looks like alibaba sets a cookie that contains the preferred currency, so that's a good place to start. Read the cookies in your browser, and try to reproduce it in your code.

Comment: I unfortunately dont know how to read the cookies in my browser. I inspected element to see if there were any names I could call in the URL but still nothing. Any more specific help would be so appreciated

Comment: looked at the cookies, and called them in the URL and still no luck. There is one more element I dont know the same of, the save button after a currency is saved, that does not seem to have cookie information and the name isnt searchable in inspect element. how to i find the name of that button pls?

Comment: Cookies are not in URLs, they are in `Cookie` HTTP headers. If you are completely new to this, I would recommend you start researching how cookies and http headers work.